# Read IP camera stream through libvlc in python and process frames in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, libvlc

I want to read from IP camera without using cv2.videocapture as the frames are jittery.

I am able to use libvlc in python to stream n display stream. However I am not able to integrate libvlc with opencv to process the individual frames from stream. Has anyone tried this in python?

Thanks

Comment: hello, can you please tell how you are able to do this uing libvlc

Answer (score 0):

There is a library [face_recognition.](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) In which you can use `face_recognition.load_image_file()` to load the image.